# How to build Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows XP?

Tags: windows-8, windows-xp, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to build Windows Phone 8 apps on Windows XP ? The SDK seems to require Windows 8.

Is my only option to use Virtual PC with Windows 8 installed on it?

Does Windows 8 apps work on Windows Phone 8 too?

Comment: Is this a joke? Windows XP is close to end of life - MS will not support it for much longer.

Comment: @Oded, its possible to develop apps for other phones on windows XP, so why not for Windows Phone 8?

Comment: Why build _anything_ on Windows XP? As I commented - it is not going to be supported for much longer.

Comment: @Oded, why not? Its the lightest OS around.

Comment: Third time. It is not going to be supported for much longer.

Comment: @Oded, i saw that the first time you said it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

In order to develop Windows Phone8 apps you need to build your code on a Windows8 machine. You can either do this by installing Windows8 on your development machine, or use a virtual machine with Windows8 installed on it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Windows 8 apps work on Windows Phone 8 too?

Unfortunelly no because of different .NET frameworks: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681690%28v=vs.105%29.aspx (Windows Phone 8 and Windows 8 platform comparison)